# Adding "Overall" group to facet_wrap (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, facet-grid

I have two groups in my data, A1 and A2. Each group has about 50% men and an approximately normal distribution of age. I want to plot a histogram of age distribution in each group, by gender, and an overall age distribution by gender (and maybe a genderless one too?).[image: age vs. density]

Is there a way to do this with facet_wrap? If not, is there a way I can manipulate my data (e.g. add a dummy variable) and add this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(iris, 
       aes(Sepal.Length, fill = Sepal.Width > 3)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

You could manipulate your data to include another copy of the dataset where Species is always "total." Then `geom_histogram` will use the full dataset for the facet corresponding to "total."

```
ggplot(iris %>%
         bind_rows(iris %>% mutate(Species = "total")), 
       aes(Sepal.Length, fill = Sepal.Width > 3)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  # I want 'total' at the end
  facet_wrap(~fct_relevel(Species, "total", after = Inf), nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Another similar solution is possible using `facet_grid()` with `margins=TRUE`: `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, fill = Sepal.Width > 3)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(. ~ Species, margins=TRUE)`

Comment: Oh that's much easier! Thanks.